# bs4.FeatureNotFound (Erro no BeaultifullSoup e parser)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Eu preciso extrair todo o texto de um html. Daí resolvi dar uma olhada no BeaultiSoup, pra ver como eu fazia isso com ele. Porém ele começou a mostrar o texto logo no inicio, eis o codigo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://servicos2.sjc.sp.gov.br/servicos/horario-e-itinerario.aspx?acao=p&opcao=1&txt='
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
lista = soup.find_all('table', class_='textosm')
print(lista)
```

O erro que ele dá é o

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ariane/PycharmProjects/extracao/teste.py", line 9, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Ariane\PycharmProjects\extracao\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py",
    line 196, in __init__  % ",".join(features))

bs4.FeatureNotFound: 
  Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.
  Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Eu fiz a instalação do `lxml` e troquei ele para `html.parse`, mas o erro continua o mesmo. 
Alguém pode dar um help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você solicitou o uso do `lxml`, lendo a mensagem de erro ele informa:

> Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.

Traduzindo:

> Não pode encontrar um construtor de estrutura/arvore com as funcionalidade que você requisitou: lxml

Se ler a documentação vai notar quais são essas funcionalidades:

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Atualmente são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aonde esta escrito "lxml’s XML parser" é informado também:

> External C dependency

Ou seja, é necessário uma lib extra, no caso o lxml:

- https://pypi.org/project/lxml/

Para instalar use no CMD:

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: lxml foi instalado sim.. Ele deu o erro, eu instalei e ele continuou dando o erro como se não tivesse ocorrido a instalação.

Comment: @ArianeMateus teu python é x64 ou x86?

Comment: x64, mas eu acabei desistindo e usei o terminal do linux para fazer o que eu precisava. Aì funcionou, obrigada

Comment: @ArianeMateus estranho, pq o teu sistema parece windows, a não ser que esteja usando Cygiwn ou algum software equivalente.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que informa o erro parece que você não tem `lxml` instalado, para instalar você pode usar um dos comandos de console abaixo.

```bsh
pip install lxml
# ou
python3 -m pip install lxml
# ^
# python que você usa para rodar os arquivos `.py`
```

[Beautiful Soup 4 Documentation - Instalando um Parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Comment: Mas o lxml está instalado.

Comment: Se você tem mais de uma versão de python instalada no seu pc, você tem que instalar nela, por isso coloquei o segundo comando, para você instalar na versão de python que você esta usando. Se você esta usando **conda** você pode instalar com esse comando `conda install lxml` lembrando que nesse caso `env` ativa também deve ser a que você esta usando para rodar o código, ou seja `source activate <nome_da_env>`

Comment: Digo isso porquê o erro está dizendo que não esta instalado e como você diz que esta sim, imagino que você possa ter instalado em outra versão do python. =D

Comment: Eu acabei rodando tudo no terminal do linux dentro do windows, aí funcionou hahaha.. Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Eu estava com o mesmo problema que você.

- Utilizo o anaconda; e através do CMD fiz a instalação do lxml no ambiente correto... Até aí tudo bem, pois estava utilizando o cmd diretamente para rodar meu algoritmo.
  Entretanto, quando tentei utilizar o terminal do vscode, encontrei esse problema aí que vc relatou.

O que eu fiz: Fui nas configurações de usuário do vscode e configurei o cmd como o "terminal.integrated.shell.windows".
Fiz isso pq notei que o problema ocorria quando utilizava o Powershell (que é o terminal integrado default do vscode).

Não sei o motivo pelo qual o Powershell dava o problema, mas depois que troquei para o cmd meu algoritimo rodava sem problemas.
Talvez vc pudesse verificar na sua IDE qual o shell utilizado. (Nos meus testes tentei o bash tbm, e o mesmo problema ocorria com o lxml).

Espero ter ajudado.
Obrigado.